# VKSdkListner не импортируется

Tags: android, вконтакте, android-studio

Скачал и подключил официальную библиотеку VK SDK к приложению, все классы работают, но не импортируется VKSDKListner. Похоже на то, что его вообще нету. В чём может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не та версия библиотеки. в 1.3.9 класс есть, в 1.5.0 - уже нет.

Comment: @zRrr Как быть в этой ситуации? Искать более старую версию или можно подключить класс отдельно?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Если новое приложение пишете - найдите пример под новую версию, если старое - скачайте предыдущую версию с гитхаба.

Comment: или в build.gradle укажите зависимость `compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.3.9'`